# How would saying "時には、" instead of "時に、" change to meaning of this paragraph?

Tags: particle-は

complete paragraph:

> それを実際に役立たせたいなどとは、まったく思っていませんでした。しかし、われわれが最初のiPhoneを設計している時に、それが私の脳裏によみがえってきたのです。
> I never thought I'd make use of that `(an idea discussed earlier)`. But, when we designed the first iPhone, i remembered that `(idea)`.

But what if I were to add "は":

> それを実際に役立たせたいなどとは、まったく思っていませんでした。しかし、われわれが最初のiPhoneを設計している時に**は**、それが私の脳裏によみがえってきたのです。

That **は** is about placing emphasis? and in that context you don't need emphasis? It would sound weird / confusing? The reader would think "*Why is emphasis placed there? Is he/she comparing it to something? It doesn't really matter, I will ignore that は and keep reading.*".

In order for "**時には** to sound natural, the context would be like:

> Macを設計している時に**は**、私は世間知らずな大学生でした。iPhoneを設計している時に**は**、社員5,000人以上の会社の社長でした。
>
> When we designed the Mac `(emphasis placed if speaking)` I was a college student who knew nothing about the world. But, when we designed the iPhone `(emphasis placed if speaking)` I was the CEO of a company with more than 5,000 employees.

To do a contrast, place emphasis on those 2 points in time?

With regard to saying **時に、** instead of **時には、**, is this explanation correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [とは、では、には Understanding of double particles](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/25742/%e3%81%a8%e3%81%af-%e3%81%a7%e3%81%af-%e3%81%ab%e3%81%af-understanding-of-double-particles)

Comment: @strawberryjam My question is much less open-ended. I'm talking about just one sentence. A pro translator wrote "~時に、" where  I wrote "~時には、". I think what I did was add a contrastive は where it is not needed. And, that makes my translation sound unnatural, but has no other impact.

Answer (score 1):

> Macを設計している**時には**、私は世間知らずな大学生でした。

- **At the time when** we designed the Mac...

> しかし、われわれが最初のiPhoneを設計している**時に**、それが私の脳裏によみがえってきたのです。

- But **when** we were designing the first iPhone...

> しかし、われわれが最初のiPhoneを設計している**時には**、それが私の脳裏によみがえってきたのです。

- But **at the time when** we were designing the first iPhone...

Comment: So, " (present-continuous verb tense + いる時に、"  comes out basically meaning "while"?

Comment: That sounds right to me. These all sound good, "while we were...~ing", "when we were...~ing", "as we were...~ing"